# How do I skip empty result or errors in this loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I do have a loop which store data into mysql...

```
/connect to your database 
//read your text file into an array, one entry per line

$lines = file('name.txt'); 

//loop through each website URL you read from the file 
foreach ($lines as $name) { 

//do some code
//Insert data to MySQL
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (data1,data2) VALUES ('$data1','$data2')");

}
```

My problem is when the code returns empty..then it gives error and stop...so how can I skip this and continue to next name so loop wont stop until it finished?

Comment: It would be better first scan through the list of basic PHP functions; there are 3 (probably there're even more) for checking emptyness of a string, and you didn't know even one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(empty(trim($line)){ continue; }
    // do your insert, etc.
}
```

If all you you want to do is check for an empty line, this will do that.

Good luck!

Comment: Note that `empty()` doesn't work on anything other than variables, so you would have to do `$line = trim($line);` before calling `empty`. But this would break of the line contained just the text `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try opening the file like so:

```
file('name.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

which might work, according to the documentation for file on php.net.

Answer (score 0):

**Empty-Check:**
`if(trim($var) == '')`

if you want to use `if(empty(trim($var)))`, please read the manual entry for empty:

> empty() only checks variables as
>   anything else will result in a parse
>   error. In other words, the following
>   will not work: empty(trim($name)).

**Skip the rest of the current loop iteration**:
If you can check this then you can use [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php). This skips the actual loop and continues with the next.

**Reading files**: As Phoenix mentioned, the following code gives you an array which represents the file:

```
// Using the optional flags parameter since PHP 5
$trimmed = file('somefile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES removes \n, but lets some empty elements in your array. 
FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES and FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES together remove empty line.
empty means only \n is in this line! **If you have a space character in it, it's not empty!**